# How can i capture a phone's number easily?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We are trying to build a product where it would be necessary for us to capture the users phone number. We would have to do this the easiest way possible for them (example just by them placing their phone close to a base). Is there a way to do this? We have thought of technologies like beacons but i understand this would require the users to download an app. We have also thought of NFC but this would only be possible on NFC enabled phones, right?

Comment: can you please provide some code, or what you have tried so far. Make your question more clear so that people can help you.

Comment: Perhaps provide a QR code that they scan to initiate a text message?  There is no way you can read it directly from the phone.